# Using SetParent to steal the main window of another process but keeping the message loops separate

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, winapi, activex

Background: My coworker and I are maintaining a million-line legacy application we inherited.  Its frontend is written in VB6, and as we're devoting almost all of our resources to converting it to C#, we are looking for quick & dirty solutions to our specific problem.

The application behaves in a plugin-ish manner.  There are up to 20ish separate ActiveX controls that can be loaded at once in a grid-style layout.  The problem is that the ActiveX controls do all of their processing on their own UI thread, and as a lot of it is blocking waiting on network access, the UI gets very soupy.  When our hosting C# app loads these controls, it becomes unresponsive because of how many controls are chewing up UI resources doing nothing.  To top it off, the controls are fragile and will crash at the slightest provocation.  When they are hosted in the main C# app, it creates serious instability.

The best my coworker and I have come up with so far is starting a process per ActiveX control.  This process, which we call the proxy, is another winforms app.  It uses named pipes to communicate with the hosting process.  The hosting process creates a window, loads an ActiveX control of our choice (via some reflections & AxHost magic), and tells the main process what its window handle is via the named pipe.  The main process uses a combination of SetParent, and SetWindowPos to move the proxy application into itself to emulate a plugin.  Size updates are sent via the named pipe.

This works well enough until the ActiveX application does some sort of lengthy process and we click around on the main window while it's working.  For awhile the main window is responsive, but eventually it becomes unresponsive as the child window waits for its UI thread.  How can we keep the child windows on their own complete thread while still getting the benefits of SetParent?

(please let me know if anything isn't clear!)

Comment: This really sounds like a good time to get off the high horse, and just implement it as a native Win32 hosting application where you get fine control over all these issues,

Comment: @ChrisBecke: *"you get fine control over all these issues"* - No, you don't. Those rules are set in stone, and there is nothing you can do to change them. (Well, you *could* file a Design Change Request with Microsoft and ask them to rewrite the windowing subsystem for you.) You call `SetParent` across threads, you attach those threads' input queues. That's not a matter of the programming language or runtime environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before. It gets messy.

We were running every plugin in its own AppDomain, which started up its own UI thread. We did this after running into lots of really nasty issues when we *didn't* use different UI threads.

It does mean that you have all the pain of communicating across AppDomains, but it's feasible. The main thing is that you'll need to run `Application.Run` in each AppDomain/plugin. Communicate between them with a huge amount of care - even shutting down is tricky.

Good luck :)

Comment: As part of the proxy (child) app, we used Application.run (new Form1()) [more or less].  The windows that start up are completely separate executables that show up in Task Manager and everything.  They still lock our UI thread when we SetParent.  :(

Comment: @insta: Hmm. That sounds distinctly odd then. If you break into the debugger, what's it blocking on?

Comment: @insta: That's to be expected, when you call [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx) (which `SetParent` across thread boundaries does), because [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043). Oh, and [is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043)

Comment: @insta: So in short: While you may have your UI nicely spread across threads (which won't work anyway), re-parenting those host processes to the same parent attaches **all** their input queues. And while one ActiveX control is handling input, none of the others (or the parent) can. Input is strictly serialized.